# Verify field format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, assertions

I'm working with data collected from difference sources which is leading to some issues for further  processing. The data I have can be recreated as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

name = ['Youssef Ahmed','Ibrahim Hassan','George','Jayden Daniel']
age = [25,44,33,22]
salary = [3300,'$2900',2000,18000]
sample_data  = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name,'Age':age,'Salary':salary})
```

Currently, I'm defining a function to verify the format of each column:

```
def age_format(age):
    """Age is a possitive int smaller that 100 """
    if type(age) != np.int64:
        return False
    if 0 < age < 100:
        return True
    return False

def name_format(name):
    """The name consist in two words separeted by a space """
    name_reg_ex = '\w+\s\w+'
    if type(name) != str:
        return False
    if re.search(name_reg_ex,name):
        return True
    return False

def salary_format(salary,max_salary=5000):
    """Salary is a possitive int smaller that max_salary  """ 
    if type(salary) != int:
        return False
    if 0 < salary < max_salary:
        return True
    return False
```

And using `assert` to check whether the format is correct or not:

```
assert all(sample_data.Age.apply(age_format)) == True, 'Wrong age format'
assert all(sample_data.Name.apply(name_format)) == True, 'Wrong Name format'
assert all(sample_data.Salary.apply(salary_format)) == True, 'Wrong Salary format'
print "THe format is correct"
```

For the given data the Age field is fine and, but both Name and Salary are wrong.

So the output I get is:

```
AssertionError: Wrong Name format
```

There are several things here I would like to improve:

1) I'm not getting any output for passing the Age assertion.
2) I would prefer to continue with the testing even if an exception      occurs.
3) If possible I would prefer to show the number of the first row at which the error occurs, this with the purpose of correct it easier.

Edit.

The output I want is something similar to this:

```
'Correct Age format'
'Error in Name format at line 3: George'
'Error in Salary format at line 2: $2900'
```

Comment: Isn't `'George' ` going to fail the `name_format` since there is only a single word (not a word separated by a space)?
Also, the comment in `name_format` should say `space` not `comma`

Comment: @nbryans Yes, it fails that's why I get: AssertionError: Wrong Name format. You're right about the space.

Comment: Ok, I thought from the question that this was unexpected for you. I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: If you don't want to do anything once an exception occurs, i.e., just "continue with the testing", then I'd forego the use of `assert` entirely and just put `print()` statements inside your functions that tell you whether they passed or not. Maybe even consider the use of Python's `unittest` module, but I think that would be overkill in this case.